# Laravel access pivot table with multiple conditions

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am having trouble with eloquent. I have 2 pivot tables that is associated with the user. These are `school_student` and `school_user`. Also I have a table for `schools` and `students`. Basically I just want to get the associated users and student based on the school of the authenticated user.

Here are the details of the tables (columns and 1 example data)

```
school_student
+----+------------+------------+------------+-----------+
| id | created_at | updated_at | student_id | school_id |
+----+------------+------------+------------+-----------+
|  1 | NULL       | NULL       | 202        | 1         |
+----+------------+------------+------------+-----------+

school_user
+----+------------+------------+-----------+---------+
| id | created_at | updated_at | school_id | user_id |
+----+------------+------------+-----------+---------+
|  1 | NULL       | NULL       |         7 |       1 |
+----+------------+------------+-----------+---------+
```

Here is what I tried

```
//get the authenticated user school
$school = Auth::user()->schools()->pluck('name'); 


$users = User::with(['roles', 'students', 'schools' => function ($q) use ($school) {
        $q->where('schools.name', $school[0]); 
 }])->take(5)->get();
```

However, the result of the query I created is somewhat correct since the school property is blank/empty BUT the students that doesn't belong to the same school of the authenticated users is still present. Can someone tell me where did I go wrong? If you are confused with the question I can edit and explain carefully at my best.

Here are the sample output

```
Result 1 //correct school and students
 School: School 1
 Students: Ace, Alex, Albert

//blank school properties
Result 2
 School: 
 Students: Tinsel, Kris, Kane //these students is from school 2 but its included

Result 3
 School: 
 Students: Nekko, Patrik, Ana //these students is from school 3 but its included

..and so on
```

Thanks guys!